# Redirect Route strict slash

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying to use strict slash with webapp2 redirect route and I'm getting this value error -

```
ValueError: Routes with strict_slash must have a name.
```

This is an example of one of my routes -

```
RedirectRoute(r'/',handler=IndexHandler,strict_slash=True)
```

It works fine if I don't have the strict_slash bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why routes with a strict_slash need to have a name, but the following should work:

```
RedirectRoute(r'/',handler=IndexHandler,strict_slash=True,name='some_name')
```