# How to do SEO Url changes and Redirects for google AppEngine Webapp2 Urls?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am moving my company website to google app engine, Its mostly static content with small sections like dates to be generated using python. I have setup everything correctly and its working fine on app engine. Now I want to make few SEO related URL changes.

This is the line of code by which the website is served now .

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', IndexPage),
    ('/discover', DiscoverPage),
    ('/about', AboutPage),
    ('/help', HelpPage),
    ('/terms-and-privacy', TermsPage)
], debug=True)
```

with classes like this defined for each page.

```
class DiscoverPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
            'bodyclass': 'discover',
        }
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('discover.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

Now the things I want to achieve are :

- when site being accessed from `www.domain.com` , I would like to redirect it to `domain.com` .

> I have added both www and non www mappings at the app engine developer console, the site is currently accessible from both www and non www urls.but I only want `non www` version

- When there is a trailing slash to the urls, strip it and send to version without trailing slash.

> Right now `domain.com/discover` works fine but `domain.com/discover/` ends up in 404 .

I haven't got much experience with python webapps and my background is mainly `apache/nginx` servers and `php` . **Does AppEngine got anything like `htaccess rules` or `nginx rewrites` ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first catch ALL requests to the "www" subdomain:

```
from webapp2_extras.routes import DomainRoute

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([

    DomainRoute('www.domain.com', [
            webapp2.Route(r'/<:.*>', handler=RedirectWWW),
    ]),

    ('/', IndexPage),
    ('/discover', DiscoverPage),
    ('/about', AboutPage),
    ('/help', HelpPage),
    ('/terms-and-privacy', TermsPage)
], debug=True)
```

with a handler that replaces the www part with the naked domain:

```
class RedirectWWW(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url = self.request.url.replace(self.request.host, 'domain.com')
        return self.redirect(url, permanent=True)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get()
```

Regarding the second issue, you could read about the `strict_slash` parameter here: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/routes.html

Answer (score 0):

@Mihail answer help to fix the issues correctly. adding some details towards his answer .

for fixing the second issue [**trailing slashes**] , if you try `strict_slash` you might end up getting this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180210/redirect-route-strict-slash) or some others.

```
ValueError: Routes with strict_slash must have a name.
```

**So documenting the steps by which i got it working**

*import `RedirectRoute` to the code*

```
from webapp2_extras.routes import RedirectRoute
```

*Change in code accordingly with name parameter*

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    DomainRoute('www.'+SITE_DOMAIN, [
            webapp2.Route(r'/<:.*>', handler=RedirectWWW),
    ]),
     RedirectRoute('/', IndexPage,strict_slash=True,name="index"),
     RedirectRoute('/discover', DiscoverPage,strict_slash=True,name="discover"),
     RedirectRoute('/about', AboutPage,strict_slash=True,name="about"),
     RedirectRoute('/help', HelpPage,strict_slash=True,name="help"),
     RedirectRoute('/terms-and-privacy', TermsPage,strict_slash=True,name="terms")
], debug=True)
```